# how convert my nested object to array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object with nested objects. In this object, each objects having two or more sub-objects. I want to get together all sub-objects into an array of data. How to do with JavaScript?

```
 const category = {
    id: 1,
    title: "a",
    level: 2,
    __parent: {
      id: 2,
      title: "b",
      level: 1,
      __parent: {
        id: 3,
        title: "c",
        level: 0,
      }
    }
  };
```

**The output I want is this**:

```
   [{
    id: 1,
        title: "a",
        level: 2,
    __parent: null
    },
    {
     id: 2,
          title: "b",
          level: 1,
    __parent: null
    
    },
    {
      id: 3,
            title: "c",
            level: 0,
    __parent:null
    
    }]
```

Comment: Hi. Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case 1**: **Using Recursion**

You can make recursive function like this:

```js
const category = {
  id: 1,
  title: "a",
  level: 2,
  __parent: {
    id: 2,
    title: "b",
    level: 1,
    __parent: {
      id: 3,
      title: "c",
      level: 0,
    }
  }
};

const result = [];

function recursiveOuput(data){
  let tempObj = {};
  Object.keys(data).map((key, index) => {
     if(typeof data[key] !== 'object'){
      tempObj[key] = data[key];
      if(!Object.keys(data).includes('__parent') && (index === Object.keys(data).length -1)){
        tempObj['__parent'] = null;
        result.push(tempObj);
      }
     }else{
      tempObj['__parent'] = null;
      result.push(tempObj);
      recursiveOuput(data[key]);
     } 
  })
  return result;
};

console.log(recursiveOuput(category));
```

---

**Case 2**: **Using While loop**

```js
const category = {
  id: 1,
  title: "a",
  level: 2,
  __parent: {
    id: 2,
    title: "b",
    level: 1,
    __parent: {
      id: 3,
      title: "c",
      level: 0,
    }
  }
};

const result = [];

let parent = category;

while (parent) {
  result.push({
    id: parent.id,
    level: parent.level,
    title: parent.title,
    __parent: null
  })
  parent = parent.__parent
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you for you'r answer can i know if i want the recursiveOuput function in (case 1) return this array of result how should be?

Comment: how could be if  recursiveOuput function in (case 1)  retun the array of data instead of pushing to another value in this case is (result)                                                                                        p.s : i want  recursiveOuput function return the array

Comment: i want recursiveOuput function return the array for example when i use this function and pass the param to this function , this function retun the array

Comment: Okay got your question. Will update my answer shortly. @sanaz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237260/discussion-between-sanaz-and-sanket-shah).

Answer (score 1):

It Be some like this :

```
 const myArray = []
const category = ...;

function foo(obj){
    myArray.push({ 
         title:obj.title,
          ....
    })
    if (obj._parent)
        foo(obj._parent)
}
foo(category)
```

Answer (score 1):

You essentially want to get the list of ancestors.

```
const ancestors = []
var parent = category
while (parent) {
  ancestors.push({
    id: parent.id,
    level: parent.level,
    __parent: null
  })
  parent = parent.__parent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use recursion to extract objects:

```js
 const category = {
    id: 1,
    title: "a",
    level: 2,
    __parent: {
      id: 2,
      title: "b",
      level: 1,
      __parent: {
        id: 3,
        title: "c",
        level: 0,
      }
    }
  };
  
function extract(obj,arr=[]){
    arr.push({...obj,__parent:null})
    if(!obj.__parent){
        return arr
    }
    
    return extract(obj.__parent,arr)    
 }

 let result = extract(category)
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-snowflake-50fex?file=/src/App.js:118-123   i use your solution but i want to create variable inside the function and return it but its return last object

Answer (score 0):

Using [Spread/Rest Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Assignment)

```js
const category = {
    id: 1,
    title: "a",
    level: 2,
    __parent: {
      id: 2,
      title: "b",
      level: 1,
      __parent: {
        id: 3,
        title: "c",
        level: 0,
      }
    }
  };

const {__parent, ...firstObject} = category;

result = [
    firstObject,
    {...category['__parent'], '__parent': null },
    {...category['__parent']['__parent'], '__parent': null},
];

console.log(result);
```